# Programmatically drive Excel files

Tags: javascript, python, excel

## The Problem

There are a bunch of excel files (complicated models hobbled together) that change a lot. A lot of different people use these files to produce reports, but don't download the latest versions so the reports are wrong.

**My First Idea**
Make a web app and allow users to interact with the master form via a website. But I can't find any JavaScript libraries that can drive Excel file (run the functions).

**Next Idea**
Use python in the background. I looked at xlwings and win32com Python libraries but it seems they just interact with the actual Excel program and not xlsx files.

## Questions

1. Is there a way to drive excel files using a web interface?
2. Is there a better way to solve the main problem of people using disparate files?

Comment: Check out [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) which is a package for working with excel files.

Comment: openpyxl doesn't run functions. It just reads and writes files.

Comment: what‘ mean of drive through web interface?in client?

Comment: Add a `autorun macro` to the `xlsx` that verify the Version with a Service running on Network Server, the same as apps checks for updates